# How to use Spring's Dependency Injection in Java EE 6 (WebSphere 8.5)?

Tags: spring, websphere, cdi, java-ee-6

We have a Spring-based application that is composed of several Java EE 5 Web Modules and runs fine in WebSphere Application Server 8.5. We use standard annotations from `javax.inject`, such as `@Inject`. Spring resolves that based on beans definietions in Spring xml files.

Now, if we upgrade our application to Java EE 6, the Application Server's CDI will attempt to resolve `@Inject` an must fail, because all of our beans are defined in Spring contexts, not in CDI contexts (we have no `beans.xml`).

Is it possible to force Spring to continue to handle `@Inject` in the Java EE 6 container (WebShpere 8.5)? I.e. disable CDI? Or does the upgrade to Java EE 6 force us to use CDI?

Comment: Is it your assumption or it is how it works? Are you sure beans.xml is missing in your module?

Comment: The question came up because I'm currently upgrading my JEE5 application to JEE6 and when ran some tests, WebSphere 8.5.5.7 failed resolving the Inject annotation and in the log I found this error:     "CWOWB0102E: A JCDI error has occurred: JCDI runtime cannot resolve @Inject java.lang.reflect.Method.setSessionValidator(SecureSessionValidator) because of a null IBMBeanManager". So it seems that WebSPhere's CDI runtime kicked in, although I do not have a beans.xml in my Web Modules. I guess that's a bug then, because CDI should only be activated at the presence of beans.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have a beans.xml in your deployment archive then CDI will not kick in and let Spring core runs the show.

Comment: Agree CDI will only work if you have beans.xml. What I can't say for certain from experience is whether Spring handling of those annotations will still work if you don't.

Comment: Yes, that is right. I found the same statement in the JEE6 tutorial at https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbnz.html

Comment: The only situation where it fails is if you put `@Inject` into a servlet. But I guess that with spring you never do that 

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on WebSphere Liberty V17.0.0.2.

Also in my case there was *no* `beans.xml` in the classpath but Weld CDI still jumped in before Spring (it was a Spring-based JSF application).

My way to deactivate Welds annotation scanning was to add the following beans.xml to the applications *WEB-INF* folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ... version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="none">
</beans>
```

As you can see, the **bean-discovery-mode** attribute has been set to **none**. That solved the issue for me.